# I try post image to Instagram by python via instabot, instagrapi but always problem with Challenge

Tags: python, instagram, instagrapi

Have anyway to resolve this problem?

My code (instabot):

```
bot = Bot()

bot.login(username="userid", password="password")

img = "photo.jpg"
bot.upload_photo(img, caption="Test post Instagram by Python")
```

My code (instagrapi):

```
api = instagrapi.Client()
api.login(username=username, password=password)

def post(post_text, image_path):
     api.photo_upload(image_path, post_text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     post(Caption, image_path)
```

Sorry but I'm newbie of Python every code from google and stackoverflow.

Comment: And what exactly is not working? Is there an error or just unexpected behaviour?

Comment: It request code from my email. I don't know how to write a code for auto resolve.